# Get an output from a <select> field with $_POST when a submit button is clicked

Tags: php, html, arrays, select, submit

I'm making a rock paper scissors game and players need to choose if they want to play best out of 1, 3, 5 or 7 before they start the game and i need it to work with a Select field and a submit button.

I am very new to the select tag but it would suit me best if the selected number could be exctracted with $_POST or $_GET

**This is the form:**

```
<form method="post">
<h1>Best out of </h1>
<select>
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="five">5</option>
    <option value="seven">7</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="start" value="START" />
</form>
```

**This is the PHP:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['one']))
    {
        echo "do something 1";
    };
    if(isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['three']))
    {
        echo "do something 2";
    };
    if(isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['five']))
    {
        echo "do something 3";
    };
    if(isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['seven']))
    {
        echo "do something 4";
    };
?>
```

Comment: `<select name="whatever">` and then you have `$_POST['whatever']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your `select` a `name`  attribute

```
<form method="post">
<h1>Best out of </h1>
<select name="my_select">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
    <option value="five">5</option>
    <option value="seven">7</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="start" value="START" />
</form>
```

After submitting your form in the PHP script you can get `select` value using `$_POST` array with index `my_select` ( `name` attribute value of the `select` element):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['my_select']))
{
    if($_POST['my_select'] === 'one'){}
    ....
}
?>
```